# Get server time by using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get the server time in a variable. I am creating a count down timer, so that i need the server time. But i don't know how to take time and assign it into a variable (that variable will be used in JavaScript ). Please help me.

Comment: It would be much easier to just echo out a timestamp in the HTML from the server, at the time the page loads, and then keep updating it with javascript etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs and if your application already has server side code you can create a service on the server side that will provide the time. Then, from JavaScript you can make a call using Ajax or Web Sockets depending on what type of service you create to request the server time.

If your app doesn't have server side code and you don't want your particular server's time you can make an Ajax call to an existing Api such as http://www.timeapi.org/ .

Comment: please give me example code @DonO